# Apply Hamming followed by FFT of wav file in Java

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to perform hamming followed by FFT of a wav file. I have implemented the same in python. How to do this in Java. I have applied hamming on the given wave file which returns a bytearrayOutputStream. Now how to perform FFT over this byteArrayOutputStream?
I am new to audio processing.  My current code is:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;


import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class AudioFFT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {


        String wavFilePath="C:\\abc.wav";
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=applyHamming(wavFilePath);
        byte[] bytesOut=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();   
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytesOut));
    }

    public static ByteArrayOutputStream applyHamming(String filePath)

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        File fileIn = new File(filePath);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
        try {
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
            int bytesPerFrame = audioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameSize();
            if (bytesPerFrame == AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED) {
                bytesPerFrame = 1;
            }
            int numBytes = 1024 * bytesPerFrame;
            byte[] audioBytes = new byte[numBytes];
            int numBytesRead = 0;

            while ((numBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(audioBytes, 0, audioBytes.length)) != -1) {

                outputStream.write(audioBytes, 0, numBytesRead);
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return outputStream;
    }


    private static int BITS_IN_BYTE = 8;

    private static AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    private static AudioFormat format;
    final static int W = 1024;

    public static void getFFT() {
        String wavFilePath="C:\\abc.wav";;
        File AudioFile = new File(wavFilePath);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in;

        try {
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFile);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        TargetDataLine line = null;
        try {

            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);

        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        line.start();
        byte[] data = new byte[W * format.getSampleSizeInBits() / BITS_IN_BYTE];
        double[] inbuf = new double[W];
        double[] fftbuf = new double[W];

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(AudioFile));
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(data)) > 0) {
                out.write(data, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        data = out.toByteArray();

        decode(data, inbuf);

        fft(inbuf, fftbuf);

    }

    public static void decode(byte[] input, double[] output) {
        assert input.length == 2 * output.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            output[i] = (short) (((0xFF & input[2 * i + 1]) << 8) | (0xFF & input[2 * i]));
            output[i] /= Short.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

    public static void fft(final double[] inputReal, double[] inputImag) {
        assert inputReal.length == 2 * inputImag.length;
        int n = inputReal.length;
        double ld = Math.log(n) / Math.log(2.0);

        if (((int) ld) - ld != 0) {
            System.out.println("The number of elements is not a power of 2.");
        }
        int nu = (int) ld;
        int n2 = n / 2;
        int nu1 = nu - 1;
        double[] xReal = new double[n];
        double[] xImag = new double[n];
        double tReal, tImag, p, arg, c, s;

        double constant;
        if (true){
            constant = -2 * Math.PI;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            xReal[i] = inputReal[i];
            xImag[i] = inputImag[i];
        }

        int k = 0;
        for (int l = 1; l <= nu; l++) {
            while (k < n) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++) {
                    p = bitreverseReference(k >> nu1, nu);
                    arg = constant * p / n;
                    c = Math.cos(arg);
                    s = Math.sin(arg);
                    tReal = xReal[k + n2] * c + xImag[k + n2] * s;
                    tImag = xImag[k + n2] * c - xReal[k + n2] * s;
                    xReal[k + n2] = xReal[k] - tReal;
                    xImag[k + n2] = xImag[k] - tImag;
                    xReal[k] += tReal;
                    xImag[k] += tImag;
                    k++;
                }
                k += n2;
            }
            k = 0;
            nu1--;
            n2 /= 2;
        }

        k = 0;
        int r;
        while (k < n) {
            r = bitreverseReference(k, nu);
            if (r > k) {
                tReal = xReal[k];
                tImag = xImag[k];
                xReal[k] = xReal[r];
                xImag[k] = xImag[r];
                xReal[r] = tReal;
                xImag[r] = tImag;
            }
            k++;
        }

        double[] newArray = new double[xReal.length * 2];
        double radice = 1 / Math.sqrt(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i += 2) {
            int i2 = i / 2;
            newArray[i] = xReal[i2] * radice;
            newArray[i + 1] = xImag[i2] * radice;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Array: " + newArray[i]);
        }

    }

    private static int bitreverseReference(int j, int nu) {
        int j2;
        int j1 = j;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= nu; i++) {
            j2 = j1 / 2;
            k = 2 * k + j1 - 2 * j2;
            j1 = j2;
        }
        return k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bytesOut` contain your wav file data (after being modified by a `Hamming window` function). These data
represent the `real part` that you should send to your `fft` method (`inputReal`). For the imaginary part, 
create an array of the same size as `inputReal`  and fill it with zeros

//create an array for the imaginary part ( I assume 1024 in length)

```
double[] imgBytesOut = new double[1024]; //imgBytesOut is not a good name for this
for(int i=0; i<1024;i++)
    imgBytesOut[i] = 0;
```

Now you have everything you need to call fft

```
fft(bytesOut, imgBytesOut);
```

Your fft method populates `xReal` and `xImg` arrays but since you declared them locally, you won't be 
able to use them after fft has finsihed (declare them as static global variables).

Also, if your file contains, say, 10000 samples and your `fft size` is 1024 samples long(`outBytes` and `imgBytesOut` are 1024 samples long)
you will have to call `fft` repeatedly to process the whole file. To get the best results, you would still need to apply `overlapping` (e.g. for a 50% overlap and fft size of 1024, you'd process samples `1-1024`, then `512-1536`, then `1024-2048` and so on).